# Identify the odd one out element

Tags: mathematics, pattern, odd-one-out

There are two columns (two sets), in each set there is a pattern among the 7 elements. The elements are not arranged in any order, the two patterns are not necessarily the same, but they are related to each other some way. In one of the columns/set one single element breaks the pattern, and this element has a logical correspondance in the other column.                Identify the two elements in question. Provide the reasoning.

[image]

This is one of my first puzzles of this kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The patterns are:

**Column 1**

> Call the numbers *a;b|c*, then *c = b/a x 3 3/4*
>  In other words, the number *c* (the one to the right of the vertical bar) can be obtained by dividing *b* over *a* and then multiplying by *3 3/4*
>  E.g.: *5 / 3 x 3 3/4 = 6 1/4*

**Column 2**

> Again, call the numbers *a;b|c*
>  The number *c* (the one to the right of the vertical bar) can be obtained by dividing *b* over *a* and then multiplying by *4 4/5*
>  E.g.: *5 / 6 x 4 4/5 = 4*

The odd ones out being:

> *4;3|2 11/16*  in column 1 and *5;4|4 4/5* in column 2.
>  In both cases the factor (that is applied to the other elements) can be formed from the numbers *a* and *b*: 4;3 -> 3 3/4 and 5;4 -> 4 4/5

Comment: this is correct